# Do HTML attributes need quotation marks?

Tags: html, web

I am working on a web site, and am wondering if you need to put quotation marks around HTML attributes for example I've seen code like:
`<img src=http://example.com/image.jpg width=350px height=200px />`
instead of:
 `<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" width="350px" height="200px" />`. 
Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: It's best practice to have double-quotes for attributes; specially for those that contain multiple elements within (i.e. `style="width:300px; height: 200px;"`, etc.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the attribute contains a string that is not ascii or has whitespace then you need to wrap it in quotes

> Attributes are placed inside the start tag, and consist of a name and
>   a value, separated by an "=" character. The attribute value can remain
>   unquoted if it doesn't contain ASCII whitespace or any of " ' ` = < or
>   >. Otherwise, it has to be quoted using either single or double quotes. The value, along with the "=" character, can be omitted
>   altogether if the value is the empty string.

link [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values)

Comment: [Updated link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#a-quick-introduction-to-html)